# Cancelling out differentials

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have been learning about differential equation on Khan Academy.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DL-ozRGDlkY

And at `1:57` Sal multiplied the whole equation by `dx` and cancelled the `dx` in `dy/dx`. But isn't `dy/dx` something like an operator. Is it mathematically correct to do such cancellation?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21199/is-frac-textrmdy-textrmdx-not-a-ratio

Answer (score -1):

So our good 'ol Sal is dealing with separable differential equations. The differential operator $\frac{dx}{dt}$ is indeed the same as $\frac{dx}{1} \cdot \frac{1}{dt}$, which means you could indeed cancel it out by multiplying both sides by one or the other. This is done because then each side may be integrated to reach a solution. As is $dx$ or $dt$ in the integral, $D=\frac{dx}{dt}$ is simply a value, and can be manipulated like any other variable.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with this. How is the operator split into a product?

Comment: A ratio of differentials (can) make sense; a ratio of a differential to a scalar does not make sense.